# Use MahApp.Metro theme to custom SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, mahapps.metro, savefiledialog

I would like to custom a `SaveFileDialog` by using the same theme than my current `window`.

I'm using `MahApps.Metro` and `MaterialDesign` and I didn't find a way to change the border as the dialog... I don't want to add thing in it, I just want to custom buttons' color, window's color etc...

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is that it's not possible.

Dialogs like `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` are using the native operating system dialogs in .NET. It means that the dialog will look and behave differently on Windows XP when compared to let's say Windows 10. Since they're not managed forms, you can't force them to use the libraries you want to.

If you really want to use the metro theme, you might need to create your own implementation of the dialog in WPF. However, I really wouldn't go that route, since it's very prone to errors and using the standard implementation by the operating system is the best choice here.

Here's ([Extend OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog Using WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42008/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-Using-WPF)) some more information about how extending an existing system dialog works using WPF. You'll quickly notice that hooking into the underlying Win32 API is tedious work but still doesn't give you much flexibility.

Comment: I read this article, but I hoped that there was a way to avoid to create it... I don't know if I'll try to customize it now... But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck if you decide to try customizing it. It's interesting but really challenging! :)